# Search files using glob() and keywords

Tags: php, regex, glob

I have a bunch of files I want to search using the `glob(pattern);` function.
I also have a text box in an HTML form that will be used as keywords.

Currently my pattern looks like this:
`glob("*.{avi,mkv,mp4,flv,mov}`
But I need to replace the `*` with the text box value as multiple keywords.

How would I do that?

Comment: Use `$_POST` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user enters a comma-separated list in the input box named `keywords`, you can use:

```
glob('*{' . $_POST['keywords'] . "}*.{avi,mkv,mp4,flv,mov}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

So if the user enters `hello,bye`, it will look for files that match the pattern

```
*{hello,bye}*.{avi,mkv,mp4,flv,mov}
```

Comment: It's not showing any results.
I'm pretty sure this makes it so that if I type in "hello", it'll only show results that have exactly "hello"?

Comment: Do you have a file named `hello.avi`, or `hello.mkv`, etc.?

Comment: No, I need it to use the values as keywords or tags, so that it'll only search files where the names contain "hello".

Comment: So it should find names like `foohello.avi`?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add wildcards around the keywords. I also forgot to put braces around it, I added that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. What if I wanted to search inside a folder?

`./vid/*{hello}*.{avi,mkv,mp4,flv,mov}` doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you're using the `GLOB_BRACE` option so that it implements expansion of `{}`.